# Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory ... Setup error: nil conf reference

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I learn to create an application using hyperledger fabrics.

This is my reference --> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html?highlight=script.sh

I got an error when create & join a channel.

When I run `peer channel create -o orderer.medrecnet.com:7050 -c medrecnetChannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls –cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/orderers/orderer.medrecnet.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.medrecnet.com-cert.pem`

After I run those command I got `error 2019-02-20 09:33:25.905 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/msp: Setup error: nil conf reference`

This is my docker-compose-base.yaml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  orderer.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: orderer.medrecnet.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    volumes:
    - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/orderers/orderer.medrecnet.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/orderers/orderer.medrecnet.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    - orderer.medrecnet.com:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=HospitalMSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/signcerts
        - peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053

  peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=doctorMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.medrecnet.com/peers/peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ../crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.medrecnet.com/peers/peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
```

This is my docker-compose-cli.yaml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  orderer.medrecnet.com:
  peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:
  peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:  

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  orderer.medrecnet.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.medrecnet.com
    container_name: orderer.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn


  peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com:
    container_name: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn


  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=HospitalMSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers/peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.medrecnet.com
      - peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
      - peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

This is my configtx.yaml:

```
---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/medrecnet.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Hospital
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: HospitalMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: HospitalMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('HospitalMSP.admin', 'HospitalMSP.peer', 'HospitalMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('HospitalMSP.admin', 'HospitalMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('HospitalMSP.admin')"

        # leave this flag set to true.
        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Doctor
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: DoctorMSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: DoctorMSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/doctor.medrecnet.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('DoctorMSP.admin', 'DoctorMSP.peer', 'DoctorMSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('DoctorMSP.admin', 'DoctorMSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('DoctorMSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer1.doctor.medrecnet.com
              Port: 7052

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Capabilities
#
#   - This section defines the capabilities of fabric network. This is a new
#   concept as of v1.1.0 and should not be utilized in mixed networks with
#   v1.0.x peers and orderers.  Capabilities define features which must be
#   present in a fabric binary for that binary to safely participate in the
#   fabric network.  For instance, if a new MSP type is added, newer binaries
#   might recognize and validate the signatures from this type, while older
#   binaries without this support would be unable to validate those
#   transactions.  This could lead to different versions of the fabric binaries
#   having different world states.  Instead, defining a capability for a channel
#   informs those binaries without this capability that they must cease
#   processing transactions until they have been upgraded.  For v1.0.x if any
#   capabilities are defined (including a map with all capabilities turned off)
#   then the v1.0.x peer will deliberately crash.
#
################################################################################
Capabilities:
    # Channel capabilities apply to both the orderers and the peers and must be
    # supported by both.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Channel is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers and peers running at the v1.3.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers and peers from
        # prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.3 channel capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers and peers on a channel are at v1.3.0 or later.
        V1_3: true

    # Orderer capabilities apply only to the orderers, and may be safely
    # used with prior release peers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        # V1.1 for Orderer is a catchall flag for behavior which has been
        # determined to be desired for all orderers running at the v1.1.x
        # level, but which would be incompatible with orderers from prior releases.
        # Prior to enabling V1.1 orderer capabilities, ensure that all
        # orderers on a channel are at v1.1.0 or later.
        V1_1: true

    # Application capabilities apply only to the peer network, and may be safely
    # used with prior release orderers.
    # Set the value of the capability to true to require it.
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        # V1.3 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.3.
        V1_3: true
        # V1.2 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.2 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set)
        V1_2: false
        # V1.1 for Application enables the new non-backwards compatible
        # features and fixes of fabric v1.1 (note, this need not be set if
        # later version capabilities are set).
        V1_1: false

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Application policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: kafka

    Addresses:
        - orderer.medrecnet.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 2s

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 10

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Orderer policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/Orderer/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    # Capabilities describes the channel level capabilities, see the
    # dedicated Capabilities section elsewhere in this file for a full
    # description
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    MedrecNetOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Hospital
                    - *Doctor
    MedrecNetChannel:
        Consortium: MedrecNetConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Hospital
                - *Doctor
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

    SampleDevModeKafka:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            OrdererType: kafka
            Kafka:
                Brokers:
                - kafka.medrecnet.com:9092

            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
            - <<: *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *Hospital
                - *Doctor
```

This is my crypto-config.yaml:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "OrdererOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing orderer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrdererOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Orderer
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: medrecnet.com   
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs" - See PeerOrgs below for complete description
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# "PeerOrgs" - Definition of organizations managing peer nodes
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PeerOrgs:
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Hospital
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Hospital
    Domain: hospital.medrecnet.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Specs"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Uncomment this section to enable the explicit definition of hosts in your
    # configuration.  Most users will want to use Template, below
    #
    # Specs is an array of Spec entries.  Each Spec entry consists of two fields:
    #   - Hostname:   (Required) The desired hostname, sans the domain.
    #   - CommonName: (Optional) Specifies the template or explicit override for
    #                 the CN.  By default, this is the template:
    #
    #                              "{{.Hostname}}.{{.Domain}}"
    #
    #                 which obtains its values from the Spec.Hostname and
    #                 Org.Domain, respectively.
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Specs:
    #   - Hostname: foo # implicitly "foo.org1.example.com"
    #     CommonName: foo27.org5.example.com # overrides Hostname-based FQDN set above
    #   - Hostname: bar
    #   - Hostname: baz
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Template"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Allows for the definition of 1 or more hosts that are created sequentially
    # from a template. By default, this looks like "peer%d" from 0 to Count-1.
    # You may override the number of nodes (Count), the starting index (Start)
    # or the template used to construct the name (Hostname).
    #
    # Note: Template and Specs are not mutually exclusive.  You may define both
    # sections and the aggregate nodes will be created for you.  Take care with
    # name collisions
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Template:
      Count: 2
      # Start: 5
      # Hostname: {{.Prefix}}{{.Index}} # default
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # "Users"
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Count: The number of user accounts _in addition_ to Admin
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Users:
      Count: 1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Doctor: See "Hospital" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Doctor
    Domain: doctor.medrecnet.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Nurse: See "Hospital" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Nurse
    Domain: nurse.medrecnet.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1  

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Lab: See "Hospital" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Lab
    Domain: lab.medrecnet.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1    

  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Administration: See "Hospital" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Administration
    Domain: administration.medrecnet.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1        
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Patient: See "Hospital" for full specification
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - Name: Patient
    Domain: patient.medrecnet.com
    EnableNodeOUs: true
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

Please help me...

Comment: update your docker images' tags to match the fabric-samples: docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools:1.4.3 hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp` in `cli` service inside your `docker-compose-cli.yaml`

Comment: or export it inside the docker cli

Comment: both are same things, I just wanted to point out where environment variables didnot match

Comment: Hi @BibekKoirala
I have done that and the error change become:




2019-02-21 11:31:01.043 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com /msp" does not exist

Comment: Can you run your cli container in bash by command ``docker exec cli -it bash`` and check if you have mounted the crypto-config folder properly in ``/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp``

Comment: Yes I have run cli container in bash by command docker exec cli -it bash. It has path --> root@297eb0f21ab1:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/peers.
There is no users folder. So how to make users folder show up?

Comment: do you have users inside ``./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users``

Comment: yes, I have two folders inside users, which is Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com and User1@hospital.medrecnet.com

Comment: In ``docker-compose-base.yaml`` file mount ``- ../crypto-config : /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto`` in your peer ``peer0.hospital.medrecnet.com``

Comment: sorry for late reply. I have added this --> working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto into docker-compose-base.yaml, but the error is still happening.

Comment: can you kill all the running containers, remove them, prune all the volumes and run the network again?

Comment: Does ``/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp`` exist in both cli and peer?

Comment: yes, it exists both in docker-compose-cli.yaml and docker-compose-base.yaml as CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH

Comment: and what about volumes?

Comment: it does not exist in volumes. Should I put also in volumes? If it should then in docker-compose-cli.yaml or docker-compose-base.yaml?

Comment: When you specify a path like ``/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp``, this is the path of your docker container. The files inside the containers must be mounted from your local file system which is specified in volumes where you specify which file or folder to mount to which path in docker. You have specified the path but not mounted the files. Mount all the files by checking what you need that may be in cli too or docker-compose.yaml file too. Hope you get it

Comment: I see...
I think you are right. To solve it I just delete /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp in docker-compose-cli.yaml and docker-compose-base.yaml, then the error is gone and the peer is running.
Thank you Bibek.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is caused because Local fabric binaries and Docker images are
  out of sync. This may cause problems. 
So would suggest you to re-download the Local package with the matching version.
Eg-

```
curl -sSL {Link) | bash -s -- <fabric_version> <fabric-ca_version> <thirdparty_version>
curl -sSL (link) | bash -s -- 1.4.4 1.4.4 0.4.18
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve it I just delete /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/hospital.medrecnet.com/users/Admin@hospital.medrecnet.com/msp in docker-compose-cli.yaml and docker-compose-base.yaml, then the error is gone and the peer is running.

Answer (score 1):

**Sol 0**

Set correctly your $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH

**Sol 1**

this is due to the absence of config.yaml , so copy it inside the peer's msp

```
  cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml
```

**Sol 2**

one possible reason is that the msp is erroneously generated. Check if the msp files are generated

by listing

```
ls  ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/xxx/users/Admin@xxx/msp
```

if not try to regenerate (In the first node)

```
fabric-ca-client register --caname ca-org1 --id.name peer1 --id.secret peer1pw --id.type peer --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/tls-cert.pem

fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://peer1:peer1pw@localhost:7054 --caname ca-org1 -M ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp --csr.hosts peer1.org1.example.com --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/tls-cert.pem
```

Sol 3
Check if the volume mapping is correct in docker-compose file

try to change

```
../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp
```

to

```
./organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer2.org1.example.com/msp
```

DEFENDING ON THE LOCATION OF YOUR DOCKER-COMPOSE FILE

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this to follow steps

1. Restart the docker - sudo systemctl restart docker
2. Then remove all the docker images by using commend
   hyperledger/fabric-orderer
   hyperledger/fabric-tools
   hyperledger/fabric-peer
   hyperledger/fabric-ccenv
   hyperledger/fabric-ca

//if hyperledger -(orderer and peer)  not pre install then

## pull to local before using it and make sure all are same version

docker pull hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.4
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.4
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.4
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:2.4
docker pull hyperledger/fabric-ca
//if docker limtit is exceeds
sudo systemctl restart docker
// Remove image in case all image are different version
docker images
docker rmi -f imageDI(5b31d55f5f3a)
docker image prune -a
// rename it to 'latest'
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.4 hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-tools:2.4 hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-peer:2.4 hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
docker tag hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:2.4 hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest

After this process is working.